# How do I bypass a regex filter that filters all html to avoid xss?

Tags: xss, regex

How do I bypass a regex filter that filters all html to avoid xss? I've tried using things like `&lt;img src="aa" onerror="alert(1)"&gt;` but still no luck. This is for a CTF challenge btw.

The regex is: `<[\s\S]*>` and the validator is running on a TypeScript server

Answer (score 2):

This filter doesn't reject unclosed tags, so you could inject:

```
<img src="x" onerror="alert(1)"
```

The tag will be closed as soon as the parser encounters a ">", which is obviously quite common in HTML contexts.

Answer (score 0):

https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet has a section on alternative characters to `<`. Here is a summary:

- %3C
- &#60, &#060, &#0060, &#00060, &#000060, &#0000060

(and try with a `;` on the end)

Also, variations on the same zero padding theme above bu with hex:

- &#x3c, &#X3c, &#x3C, &#X3C

And:

- \x3c, \x3C, \u003c, \u003C

Comment: I've tried bypasses like this, but it still detects them.